# How to use nearby notifications API of Google Proximity Beacon?

Tags: rest, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

How to can we send near by notification from rest client.
i have api key created in google developer console but when i check it gave me unauthorised.
Can anyone have demo of send nearby notifications using beacon beacon.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/developer_faq